# Is it feasible to edit the report exported by Power BI into Powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint, powerbi

My question is after I export the Power BI report into Powerpoint, is it feasible to edit the PPT report such as change the color and change the data?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to edit a Power BI report's data or formatting once exported to PowerPoint. The following happens when exporting your report to PPT:

- Each page in the Power BI report becomes an individual slide in
  PowerPoint
- Each page in the Power BI report is exported as a single
  high resolution image in PowerPoint
- Text boxes in the Power BI report
  become editable text boxes in PowerPoint
- A link is created in PowerPoint that links to the Power BI report

Because the pages are exported to images, the data can no longer be modified without re-exporting.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-powerpoint